Is there a procedure to convert two extensive-form game trees into one Blue-Red Hackenbush graph?
In this paper, a Blue-Red Hackenbush graph is converted into an extensive-form game tree (the type often studied in non-combinatorial game theory) given the assumption that it's Blue's turn.  A second extensive-form game tree exists given the assumption that it's Red's turn.  Perhaps it is a bit generous to credit the paper for actually doing the conversion; more accurately it asserts that it can be done and gives an example, but the procedure is intuitive and I was able to replicate it for a toy Blue-Red Hackenbush graph.  The pair of extensive-form game trees seems to be unique, up to isomorphisms which are generally irrelevant in extensive-form games (reordering the edges and so forth).
Is there a procedure to go in the opposite direction and convert any two extensive-form game trees with the appropriate properties (zero-sum, two players, one player starts in each tree, players alternate turns, no randomness in nature, no information sets) into a single, unique Blue-Red Hackenbush graph, up to isomorphisms which are generally irrelevant in Hackenbush (sliding vertices along the ground, etc.)?  It would be important to preserve not just the (expected) value of the games assuming rational strategies, but their entire choice set structure.  I'm thinking of the idea of using a Blue-Red Hackenbush graph to losslessly compress the structure of an extensive-form game tree, perhaps by merging it with some intelligently selected second extensive-form game tree.  Of course, it should follow that the surreal number value of the Blue-Red Hackenbush game agrees in some sense with the (expected) value of the extensive-form games.  Is this feasible, and if so, how?

Do you want to do something like this with all extensive forms, or only the ones that happen to arise in Blue-Red Hackenbush?

@MarkS. Well, my expectation is that this will not be possible for all extensive forms, but hopefully all extensive forms given some intuitive restrictions (perhaps constant-sum, two-player, alternating turns).
